# Getting Invalid Argument Exception in selenium code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
public class uploadfilelearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        "C:/Users/3520/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
        driver.get("https://leafground.com/file.xhtml");
        
        WebElement uploadfile = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt89_input"));
        uploadfile.click();
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\3520\\Downloads\\TestLeaf Logo.png");
                    
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection, null);
        
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            
                
    }

}
```

On running above code getting below error
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument.
Please help to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, selenium is not able to perform `click()` on the INPUT node.

If your intention is to upload the file, replace the entire below code:

```
WebElement uploadfile = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt89_input"));
uploadfile.click();

Thread.sleep(3000);

StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\3520\\Downloads\\TestLeaf Logo.png");

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection, null);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(4000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

To:

```
WebElement uploadfile = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt89_input"));
uploadfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\3520\\Downloads\\TestLeaf Logo.png");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    
    
    public class uploadfilelearning {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
            "enter your chromedriver.exe file path");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             //navigating to leafGround Website

            driver.get("https://leafground.com/file.xhtml");

            //inspecting the BASIC UPLOAD field to upload Any File

            WebElement uploadfile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='file'])[1]"));

            //Creating relative Path Of an file By passing the XPath of the file 
            File file=new File("pass your file XPath");
            //conventing the relative Xpath file into absolute Xpath to work on all the Pc's
            String file1=file.getAbsolutePath();

           //sendkeys method is also used to send the file to upload files so I'm passing the absolute xapth of an file 
           
            uploadfile.sendKeys(file1);
            Thread.sleep(3000);             
        }
    
    }
    
    
    use By.xpath("(//input[@type='file'])[1] TO UPLOAD FILE IN BASIC UPLOAD
    USE By.xpath("(//input[@type='file'])[2] TO UPLOAD FILE IN ADVANCE UPLOAD 
    
    THIS CODE WORK TILL uploading the file 
     don't inspect any element having values in numbers like  (By.id("j_idt88:j_idt89_input"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).